# How to parse asp response with jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic, get

I have a simple lookup form that gets data from an asp server. Once a user submits the form, a table is updated on the same page. I'm trying to convert the lookup to use ajax so that only the tables reload instead of the entire page. but how do I pass an asp variable as the data value to pass to the server? and how do I actually parse the data returned from the asp server? How I currently have it setup I get no response. If I hardcode a data value, and do alert "test" the ajax call works.. Any help for a noob would be appreciated!

getinfo.asp

```
<form name="form" method="get" action="getinfo.asp">
    <input id="appendedInputButton" name="txtsearch" value="<%=txtSearch%>" type="text">
    <button id="submitform" type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault();" >Search</button>
</form>

<div id="showresults">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name: <%=name%></td>
        <td>Email: <%=email%></td>
        <td>Phone: <%=phone%></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>

    <script>
        $('#submitform').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            url: "getinfo.asp",
            data: {
                txtsearch: $('#appendedInputButton').val()
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType : "html",
            success: function( html ) {
                $('#showresults').html(html, '#showresults');
            },
            error: function( xhr, status ) {
                alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
            },
            complete: function( xhr, status ) {
                alert( "The request is complete!" );
            }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if <%=name%> is an ASP thing but you should be alerting this:

```
 alert( html );
```

Because that is what your success call is storing it into:

```
success: function( html /* <- This is what you should alert */ ) {
    alert( <%=name%> );
},
```

I just re-read your entire question. Are you looking to do this as well?

```
data: {
               // this gets the value of your input with the id='appendedInputButton'
    txtsearch: $('#appendedInputButton').val()
},
```

Comment: These are comments, not an answer.

Comment: Did these suggestions all fail? Does your getinfo.asp page actually produce html code for your AJAX to take in?

Comment: My bad. I focused on his question rather than the possibility that it's just because his code isn't working. SO won't let me undo the downvote. Consolation: it cost me a reputation point anyway.

Comment: It's cool, I don't personally know ASP but I do know a thing or two about AJAX so I always strive to both teach and learn :)

Comment: I want to only load a specific element from the html response. Do I use .html? .replaceWith? .load?

Comment: It depends...I am looking at the code from your question and I would like to know, are you using AJAX to call the same page that the user is currently viewing? Like if I am on your site then does my URL look like www.example.com/getinfo.asp ?

Answer (score 0):

I have my server return XML and then parse it with jQuery:

PHP (you'd have to translate this to ASP, of course):

```
$dom = new DOMImplementation();
$document = $dom->createDocument();
$document->formatOutput = true;
$document->preserveWhitespace = true;

$functionResult = $document->createElement('FunctionResult');
$document->appendChild($functionResult);

$functionStatus = $document->createElement('FunctionStatus');
$functionResult->appendChild($functionStatus);

$ingredients = $document->createElement('Ingredients');
$functionResult->appendChild($ingredients);

$ingredient = $document->createElement('Ingredient');
$ingredients->appendChild($ingredient);

$success = true;
$message = 'Request successful; ';

$functionStatus->setAttribute('function', $function);
$functionStatus->setAttribute('success', $success);
$functionStatus->setAttribute('message', addslashes($message));

// Now respond to the requestor
Header("Content-type: text/xml", 1);
robLog("\nAjax result:\n" . stripslashes($document->saveXML()), false, true);
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Give you XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FunctionResult>
  <FunctionStatus function="getIngredients" success="1" message="Request successful"/>
  <Ingredients>
    <Ingredient>
    ...
    </Ingredient>
  </Ingredients>
</FunctionResult>
```

Which you can parse like this:

```
$('Ingredient', xml).each(function() {
    var ingredientDescriptor = {};

    $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attribute) {
        var name = attribute.name;
        var value = attribute.value;
        ingredientDescriptor[name] = value;
    });
}
```